# Ajax with tokens

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How would you go about using tokens with the following?

`$('#DIV').load('child.php?id='+id);`

So that you couldn't access child.php straight from the browser and type child.php?id=1

If this is not possible with tokens would there be any other way?

Thought about XMLHttpRequest as follows:

```
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest();
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){ 
        if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){ 
            document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = mygetrequest.responseText;
        } else{ 
            alert("An error has occured making the request");
        }
    }
}
mygetrequest.open("GET", "child.php?id="+id, true);
mygetrequest.send(null);
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to check if the request is an ajax request (from `load()`) or not, this can be done by the following:
child.php:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // it's an ajax request validate id and continue!
} else {
    // this is not an ajax request, get out of here!
}
```

Comment: hi didnt see your comment sorry, would the edit element I added in the question work then?

Comment: @Alie: 1) why using JS if you are already loading jQuery 2) if you want to check if the user is accessing the `child.php` file from ajax request or from the address bar, then the way I provided would do that

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery post to send the parameters "behind the scene" and then check if the request was sent from a certain location or IP within the actual php file. If the location or IP does not have the authority to access it, simply output an error using e.g. the `die()` method before anything else has been output.

Comment: post inputs can easily get manipulated! and setting an IP is not a generic solution!

Comment: I do realize that post inputs may be manipulated, thus the IP protection, so to speak. And using the `$_SERVER` variable in PHP to get the IP would get rid of any problems with dynamic IPs. It would also limit the requests to the server only. Which, I am guessing, is enough for OP's issue.